# How to remove specific strings from a list in pyspark dataframe column

Tags: python, pyspark

I have the below python list.

`lst=['name','age','country`']

Spark dataframe is below.

```
column_a
name Xxxx, age 23, country aaaa
name yyyy, age 25, country bbbb
```

I have to compare the list with spark dataframe string column and remove the values from list from the column.

Expected output is:

```
column_a
Xxxx, 23, aaaa
yyyy, 25, bbbb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `regexp_replace` with `'|'.join()`.  The first is commonly used to replace substring matches. The latter will join the different elements of the list with `|`. The combination of the two will remove any parts of your column that are present in your list.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = df.withColumn('column_a', F.regexp_replace('column_a', '|'.join(lst), ''))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you don't want to import any additional modules you can also use something like this:

```
df['column_a'] = df['column_a'].apply(lambda x: ''.join([i for i in x.split() if i not in lst]))
```

Comment: Thank you . I will check this option too

Comment: isn't this ```pandas``` ?

Comment: oh, I think I didn't read carefully, I assumed OP has a pandas df, so pandas operations wouldn't be additional. You are right